# SQL Query to get data from two tables with one to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query some data from SQL Server database but can't figure out how to write the query to get the desired data. Below is the scenario.

A CaseMaster can have multiple CaseStages (Preliminary, Appeal, Execution, Reconciliation etc.) and each CaseStage may have one of the statuses like New, In Progress, Closed, Adjudicated, On Hold etc.).

I want to get all cases whose stage's status is "In Progress" or if stage's status is not in Progress then only last stage whose status is "Adjudicated". In the result set, for each case, either that stage should appear which is "In Progress" or only last one which is "Adjudicated" (not both).

Below is what I have tried so far, but it shows both "In Progress" and "Adjudicated".

```sql
SELECT
    TOP (100) PERCENT
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_name,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_case_no,
    dbo.CaseStages.case_type,
    dbo.CaseStages.company_role,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_start_date,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_status, 
    dbo.CaseStages.case_id,
    dbo.CaseMaster.file_number
FROM
    dbo.CaseStages INNER JOIN
    dbo.CaseMaster ON dbo.CaseStages.case_id = dbo.CaseMaster.id
WHERE
    ( dbo.CaseStages.stage_status = 'In Progress' )
    OR
    ( dbo.CaseStages.stage_status <> 'In Progress')
    AND
    ( dbo.CaseStages.stage_status = 'Adjudicated')
GROUP BY
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_name,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_case_no,
    dbo.CaseStages.case_type,
    dbo.CaseStages.company_role, 
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_start_date,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_status, 
    dbo.CaseStages.case_id, 
    dbo.CaseMaster.file_number
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your query is way more complicated than the explanation would suggest.

Comment: Also, `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT...` is a code-smell. There's no good reason for using that in a production query.

Comment: You really shouldn't be including the table's schema when referencing a column. Instead you should be using *good* aliases for your tables (object) and using those as the prefix when you reference a column. Using the schema name is deprecated, and your code will stop working in a future version of SQL Server.

Comment: Why the `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: When using `OR` you should really be using parentheses (`()`) to group the clauses as well; otherwise the query may well not behave as you expect.

Comment: The query i have posted above is generated through View creation dialog. and Group By is there because for each CaseMaster, I want to see one Stage (either the one with In Progress Status or the one with Adjudicated status)

Comment: But `GROUP BY` is for when you are performing aggregation, @WAQ . There is no aggregation in your query, so there should not be a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Can you pls add some sample data

Comment: sample data is added

Comment: So you want to see data with status 'Adjudicated' and 'In Progress'?

Comment: @AA Either In Progress, or if none is in Progress then only the last stage which is Adjudicated. Please note that multiple stages per case can be Adjudicated. So I want to see the last one which was Adjudicated if there is no stage which is in Progress state

Comment: How do we identify the last Adjusticated case ? Any stage wise ordering we can give?

Comment: @AA by stage_end_date

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_name,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_case_no, 
    dbo.CaseStages.case_type, 
    dbo.CaseStages.company_role, 
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_start_date, 
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_status, 
    dbo.CaseMaster.file_number
FROM
(
    select 
        A.stage_name,
        A.stage_case_no, 
        A.case_type, 
        A.company_role, 
        A.stage_start_date, 
        A.stage_status, 
        A.file_number 
    FROM dbo.CaseStages A
    where dbo.CaseStages.stage_status = 'In Progress'
    union all
    select 
        A.stage_name,
        A.stage_case_no, 
        A.case_type, 
        A.company_role, 
        A.stage_start_date, 
        A.stage_status, 
        A.file_number
    from dbo.CaseStages A
    left join 
    (
        select distinct case_id 
        from dbo.CaseStages b 
        where b.stage_status = 'In Progress'
    )B
    on a.case_id=b.case_id
    where a.stage_status = 'Adjudicated'
    and b.case_id is null
)A
INNER JOIN dbo.CaseMaster 
ON A.case_id = dbo.CaseMaster.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (Not tested)

```
SELECT 
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_name,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_case_no,
    dbo.CaseStages.case_type,
    dbo.CaseStages.company_role,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_start_date,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_status, 
    dbo.CaseStages.case_id,
    dbo.CaseMaster.file_number
FROM
    dbo.CaseStages INNER JOIN
    dbo.CaseMaster ON dbo.CaseStages.case_id = dbo.CaseMaster.id
WHERE
    ( dbo.CaseStages.stage_status = 'In Progress' )

union

SELECT
    TOP (1) 
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_name,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_case_no,
    dbo.CaseStages.case_type,
    dbo.CaseStages.company_role,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_start_date,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_status, 
    dbo.CaseStages.case_id,
    dbo.CaseMaster.file_number
FROM
    dbo.CaseStages INNER JOIN
    dbo.CaseMaster ON dbo.CaseStages.case_id = dbo.CaseMaster.id
WHERE   
     dbo.CaseStages.stage_status = 'Adjudicated'
ORDER BY     
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_end_date  desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you have 2 different criteria, one involving the latest date and the other just the in-process record, this should work. I have no data to test with so it was not tested:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_name,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_case_no,
    dbo.CaseStages.case_type,
    dbo.CaseStages.company_role,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_start_date,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_status, 
    dbo.CaseStages.case_id,
    dbo.CaseMaster.file_number
FROM
    dbo.CaseStages INNER JOIN
    dbo.CaseMaster ON dbo.CaseStages.case_id = dbo.CaseMaster.id
WHERE
    ( dbo.CaseStages.stage_status = 'In Progress' )

UNION ALL

SELECT stage_name, stage_case_no,case_type,company_role,stage_start_date,stage_status,case_id,file_number
FROM 
(SELECT
    MAX(dbo.CaseStages.stage_end_date) EndDate, 
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_name,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_case_no,
    dbo.CaseStages.case_type,
    dbo.CaseStages.company_role,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_start_date,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_status, 
    dbo.CaseStages.case_id,
    dbo.CaseMaster.file_number
FROM
    dbo.CaseStages INNER JOIN
    dbo.CaseMaster ON dbo.CaseStages.case_id = dbo.CaseMaster.id
WHERE  
     dbo.CaseStages.stage_status = 'Adjudicated'
GROUP BY dbo.CaseStages.stage_name,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_case_no,
    dbo.CaseStages.case_type,
    dbo.CaseStages.company_role,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_start_date,
    dbo.CaseStages.stage_status, 
    dbo.CaseStages.case_id,
    dbo.CaseMaster.file_number)
```